# embedded resources paths change

Tags: c#, .net-core, embedded-resource

At work we use the EmbeddedFileProvider to load SQL files and access the files via relative paths to the resource like so: `path/to/file.sql`.

Yesterday I worked on a private project and thought I could use this to read some files I need in my program but it did not work and when I checked the output of `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` I noticed the names of the resources did not include any path so I tried referencing them by just their filenames and it worked.

Today I checked out the same project on my Laptop and tried running it only to get an Exception in my resource loader, that the files could not be found. After checking `GetManifestResourceNames()` again I saw that the resource names changed the format to `path.to.resource.txt`. How can this be? I used the same dotnet sdk everytime and the only difference was the machine the code ran on. I even had the exact same OS installed.

```cs
public static class EmbeddedResourceLoader
{
    public static byte[] Load(string name)
    {
        var provider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
        using var resourceStream = provider.GetFileInfo(name).CreateReadStream();
        using var reader = new BinaryReader(resourceStream);
        return reader.ReadBytes((int)resourceStream.Length);
    }
}
```

This is my implementation of the resource loader and the files are located relative to the project directory inside an `assets` folder.